# Javascript variable not displayed in HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

Whats wrong with my code . The title is not displayed within the div banAdT :

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>
        Banner Ad Name :<br />
        <input type="text" name="bannerAdName" id="bannerAdName" />
    </p>
    <p>
        Your web page :<br />
        <input type="text" name="bannerAdWeb" id="bannerAdWeb" />
    </p>
    <p>
        Ad image :<br />
        <input type="file" name="bannerAdImage" id="bannerAdImage"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        Title :<br />
        <input type="text" name="bannerAdTitle" id="bannerAdTitle" />
    </p>
    <p>
        Description :<br />
        <textarea name="bannerAdDesc" id="bannerAdDesc" ></textarea>
    </p>
    <div id="button"><input type="button" value="VIEW" onclick="return upload()"/></div>

    <input type="hidden" value="POST" />
</form>
<div id="popupContact">
        <a id="popupContactClose">x</a>
        <div id="contactArea">
            <div id="banAdT">
                <script>document.write(document.getElementById("bannerAdTitle").value);</script> <!-- Displays nothing -->
            </div>
            <img src="" id="preview" width="120" height="120" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because when the script runs, the element `bannerAdTitle` won't have a value. I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but you probably want to attach a `change` event listener to the `bannerAdTitle` input, and write the value from there:

```
document.getElementById("bannerAdTitle").onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById("banAdT").innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

That will write the value of `bannerAdTitle` in the `banAdT` element every time the change event is fired.

Answer (score 2):

`document.write` is executed as the page loads, but at that point you haven't given `bannerAdTitle` a value - the INPUT is empty.

Comment: OK,so how can I display the value ?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do. Are you trying to update the div every time the text in the INPUT changes? In which case, you need to handle the `onchange` event of the INPUT.